# Value Error:unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index %Id

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to insert integer values in my table, But i was subjected to "Value Error"

```
import psycopg2

def connect():
    con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists books(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT NOT NULL,author TEXT NOT NULL,year integer NOT NULL,isbn integer NOT NULL)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%d,%d)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()


connect()
insert("the sun","helen",1997,23456777)
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

From  the [Psycopg FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#problems-with-type-conversions):

> Q: I can’t pass an integer or a float parameter to my query: it says a
>   number is required, but it is a number!
>
> A: In your query string, you always have to use %s placeholders, even when passing a number. All Python objects are converted by Psycopg in
>   their SQL representation, so they get passed to the query as strings.
>   See Passing parameters to SQL queries.

So I guess you just have to replace the `%d` with `%s`.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have another error - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: That's a different problem then. But thanks for the downvote!